# Can postdoc offers be delayed a few months?

Tags: phd, postdocs, job

I am a PhD student in cybersecurity. I am close to finishing my PhD. I need to submit one paper to a journal and write one conference paper, then I am ready to write my thesis.

I got a postdoc position in a great research lab. The tentative start date is the beginning of May. They asked for a letter from my supervisor, stating that I am going to defend before the beginning of May. However, my supervisor keeps on telling me he can only state that I can submit my thesis before that date. He wrote a letter for that. I am worried that I may miss the opportunity because of my supervisor. I am not happy in the country in which I am doing my PhD. So, I want to get out of this country, too.

My question: can postdoc offers usually be delayed for a short time? Do they allow the student to start working after they submit their thesis even if they did not defend yet?

Answer (score 2):

> Can postdoc offers usually be delayed for a short time?

Maybe, maybe not.  It depends on several factors that may or may not be under the control of the research lab.  There is no general answer to this question, and a statistical answer, if it exists, will not help you.

> Do they allow the student to start working after they submit their thesis even if they did not defend yet?

See above.

You will have to contact the research lab in question directly with this question.